# Fuzzy graphics after suspend win nvidia drivers

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

I usually get this weird artifacts when the system comes back from a `suspend` state.

Example:

> Top bar:
> [image: fuzzy top bar]

> a Chromium window:
> [image: fuzzy chromium window]

I'm now running a fresh install of pop_os `20.04` with the nvidia driver version `440.100` on a `GTX 1070 Max-Q`.
I switched from ubuntu 20.04 because of the alleged better graphics support.

It seems like there's an issue with the memory address read from the GPU...

*Note*:
Here's a similar issue with `Intel` based graphics:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04
.
My issue only happens after a `suspend`, not a startup and I (think) am using the discrete GPU only.

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA has a number of scripts you must add to your systemd suspend/resume (`systemd-hibernate.service.requires` and `systemd-suspend.service.requires`) in order to fix the issue. For more info, please read:

https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/450.57/README/powermanagement.html